# Prevent select HTML element from overflowing parent width

Tags: html, css

I have a parent container with fixed length. It has two children: span and select. There's a problem that select overflows parent when option name is very long.

I would like the select to not grow past parent width.

Here's a codepen: https://codepen.io/dostu/pen/eYrPKjZ

EDIT: The select options are dynamic in my case. When they are short I would like to keep the select's original width and not fill the parent 100%.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>Style</span>
  <select>
    <option>Very very very long option</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36247140/why-dont-flex-items-shrink-past-content-size)

Comment: Short answer though is that putting `width: 100%` on the `select` will handle it.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In my case the content of select is dynamic. When it's short I would like to keep the select small and not grow to fill parent width.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this by adding a container around the `<select>` element with a `min-width` of `0` and then setting the `max-width` on the `<select>` to `100%`.

The `min-width: 0` on the container overrides the default min width for flex items and allows the container to shrink past the content size, as described in: [Why don't flex items shrink past content size?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36247140/8068625).

The `max-width: 100%` on the `<select>` element prevents it from overflowing its container.

Here's an example (with both long and short option values):

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  width: 150px;
  height: 50px;
  background-color: #ddd;
}

.select-wrapper {
  min-width: 0;
}

select {
  max-width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <span>Style</span>
  <div class="select-wrapper">
    <select>
      <option>Very very very long option</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="container">
  <span>Style</span>
  <div class="select-wrapper">
    <select>
      <option>Opt</option>
    </select>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -1):

You can hide the overflow of the parent element, any element bigger than the parent element won't be visible past the parent size. You can as well set a max-width for the child element, so it doesn't go larger than the parent element.

I edited your codepen:

HTML

```
<div class="container">
    <span>Style</span>
    <select class="option">
        <option>Very very very long option</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 150px;
    height: 50px;
    background-color: #ddd;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.option {
    max-width: 100px;
}
```

Comment: This causes the arrows of select element to get clipped. I would like them to still be visible. BTW it's not me who downvoted you :)